# Can we use the Rad Controls to use in Asp.net MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, telerik-mvc

I am using Asp.net mvc telerik Controlls in my application.

Can we use RAD Controlls in my asp.net mvc? application?

If not why so? what is the problem we can not use those controlls in Asp.net mvcv?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use those controls in an ASP.NET MVC application because they rely on ViewState and PostBack model, all notions that no longer exist in MVC. Also those controls use DataSources to bind their data. Data Sources are no-no in MVC.

Comment: Thanks Darin, But I do see some documents online to use RadControls in asp.net mvc? is that right?http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/radcontrols-for-aspnet-mvc-overview.html

Comment: Yes, I see the [some examples](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/mvc-radgrid-databinding.html), this is not MVC. Those are some hacks that violate the pattern just to make something work. Those controls are not intended to be used in like this and I wouldn't recommend you doing it. Consider using the [controls specifically designed for ASP.NET MVC](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-mvc.aspx) or use standard WebForms.

Comment: Tell your authorities that those controls are not designed to work with the MVC pattern and it would be better to use the controls designed for this. If you used them you would write code which is difficult to maintain later because it will rely on concepts which are not common in MVC applications (viewstate, postback, data sources and data binding).

Comment: Thanks Darin, But they need to proof from Telerik people that we can not use Rad Controls..:) how to do that?

Comment: @kumar, why not ask the guys from Telerik directly? They will probably tell you that you could use their components in an ASP.NET MVC application and even provide you with an example. But be aware that the code you will be writing is against good practices.

Answer (score 2):

Telerik does make some controls specifically for ASP.NET MVC, have you looked at [those](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-mvc.aspx)?

Comment: Yes KOTJMF..I am using those things now.. Thanks